# Two almost identical functions, one works, the other does not?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, restsharp

Working on writing a C# app to talk to our ServiceNow API.  For some reason I can successfully ignore the root token of the JSON file it returns for the user, but not for the Incident.  JSON returns seem to be almost identical save for the fact that one is from the incident table and the other is from the `sys_user` table.

Tried a couple of different ways of using Newtonsoft in the process of getting to the ignoring of the root token. Which has led me to where this code is at now (albeit unrefined)

```
void incidentCreator(string incID)
{
    var restRequest = new RestRequest(_incTableLink + "/" + incID);
    restRequest.AddParameter("sysparm_display_value", "true");
    restRequest.AddParameter("sysparm_fields", "assigned_to,number,sys_updated_on,sys_id,comments_and_work_notes");
    string incidentJsonString = _restInteractions.querySnow(restRequest);
    Incident incident = null;
    try
    {
        incident = JObject.Parse(incidentJsonString).SelectToken("result[0]").ToObject<Incident>();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    _incidentList.Add(incident);
}

void userGetter(string userID)
{
    var restRequest = new RestRequest(_userTableLink);
    restRequest.AddParameter("sysparm_query", "sys_id=" + userID);
    string userJsonString = _restInteractions.querySnow(restRequest);
    User user = null;
    try
    {
        user = JObject.Parse(userJsonString).SelectToken("result[0]").ToObject<User>();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    //User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(userJsonString);
    _userList.Add(user);
}
```

JSON string for incident that doesn't work

```
"{
  \"result\": {
    \"number\": \"INC1215653\",
    \"sys_id\": \"52764be80007fb00903d51fea4ade50f\",
    \"comments_and_work_notes\": \"2019-08-01 10: 46: 19 - PERSON (Additional comments)\\nEmailed PERSON 
admin of the site to check permissions\\n",
    \"sys_updated_on\": \"2019-08-01 10: 46: 17\",
    \"assigned_to\": \"Employee\"
  }
}"
```

JSON string for user which does work

```
"{
  \"result\": [
    {
      \"calendar_integration\": \"1\",
      \"last_position_update\": \"\",
      \"u_lmc_account_indicator\": \"\",
      \"u_supply_chain\": \"false\",
    }
  ]
}"
```

No matter what I do with the `incidentCreator()` JSON parsing, using jsonconvert or the implementation present in current shared code.  I either get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." or just an object with all it's variables being null.

Any ideas? I'm sorry for the stripped back user json, it is a huge string and i couldn't be bothered cleaning it of PII before posting.

Comment: One obvious difference is that the second instance is an array, whereas the first isn't, so you might need to parse to List<User>

Comment: What is the declaration of Incident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPath expression in your `incidentCreator` is incorrect.

It should be:-

```
try { incident = JObject.Parse(incidentJsonString).SelectToken("result").ToObject<Incident>(); }
```

Also, It's possibly just a result of pasting the JSON into the question, but the "comments_and_work_notes" field of the incident JSON example isn't escaped properly; just check you're receiving valid JSON using a linter to be sure.

Comment: thanks, I think I was staring at this for too long to see the problem.  I must have tried every version of code except this lol

Answer (score 0):

The second JSON contents an array. You can see the différences `[` (array) and `{` (object) after the word `result`

To parse for the case `user`, try it

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
var listUser = new List<User>();
foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {
        string name = p.Name;
        string value = (string)p.Value;
        var user = new User();
        user.Name = name;
        ...... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your JSON string for incident has the field `result` which stores an object and the JSON string for user has the field `result` which contains an array of one object
incident

```
{
    result :
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

user

```
{
    result :
    [
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

so the query `SelectToken("result[0]")` will work for the user since the `result` field contains an array with an element at index 0, but it wont work for the incident since there the `result` field does not conatin an array.

But `SelectToken("result").ToObject<Incident>()` should give you your `Incident` object.